# how to use wj to bucket a list of timestamps in a table

Tags: kdb

I have a table that's aggregated by date, sym and client_type. The rest of the cols are not aggregated but rather lists.

So for example :

```
table2: select requestId, initialTimestamp by date, sym, client_type, from table
```

requestId and initialTimestamp are therefore lists.

I want to basically find duplicate data within 5 minutes and mark them as so.

if my 5 mins are fixed then I could do something like:

```
table3: update bucket:  (5 xbar\:`minute$initialTimestamp) from table2;
```

and then ungroup and work with the bucket to identify dupes... e.g

```
table4: select requestId by bucket, sym, client_type ungroup table3;
update duplicateId: ` from (ungroup update duplicateId: ?[(count each requestId)>1; requestId@'1; `] from table4) where requestId=duplicateId
```

This works nicely, but what If I wanted a 5 min rolling window instead of a fixed window?

it seems to point to a wj - but I'm not sure how to make it work with a grouped column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to find duplicates you could possibly use `fby` rather than time buckets/windows?

```
select from table where 1 < (count;initialTimestamp) fby ([]date;sym;client_type;requestId)
```

Edit: I still think wj is unnecessary and won't be that efficient. You could do update by group like so:

```
// given the following dummy table

t:update time:"P"$"D" sv/: flip(string[date];string[time]) from ([]date:raze 20#'.z.d+til 5;sym:100?`symA`symB`symC;time:10:00+til 100;clientType:100?`clientA`clientB;requestId:100?3);

update dup:00:05>=deltas time by date,sym,clientType,requestId from t
```

Edit: Since you want the first duplicate when there are multiple then I think `wj` may be the only way as you originally wanted. You want to use `wj1` as `wj` will consider the prevailing row before entering the time window.

```
// sort by grouping then time
t2:`date`sym`clientType`time xasc t; 
times:-00:05 -00:00:00.000000001 +\:t2`time;

// params
// pair of time lists
// common columns/grouping with time last
// tableToJoinTo
// (windowJoinTable;(function;col))

wj1[times;`date`sym`clientType`time;t2;(update dupId:requestId from t2;(first;`dupId))]
```

Comment: after I group them, I want to mark as duplicates if they are within a 5 min sliding/rolling windows. That's the bit I'm struggling with

Comment: see edit if that can suit your requirement

Comment: yes!! I think this works beautifully!  but without the  requestId in the by clause. If I wanted to add another column called duplicateId that is always referring to the original one how would I do it? I tried something like update dup:00:05>=deltas time, dupId: ?[00:05>=deltas time; prev requestId; -1] by date, sym, clientType from t. This somewhat works, but I'd like to get the Id of the "original" if you like.   Using first requestId goes beyond the 5 minute interval

Comment: hmm, I think if you specifically want the first id when there are multiple duplicates then you may have no choice but to use `wj`. See edit